# Why Pylint says print('foo', end='') is an invalid syntax?

Tags: python, pylint

This very simple code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print('foo', end='')
```

Makes Pylint unhappy (both on Python2 and Python3):

```
pylint ./pylint.py
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module pylint
E:  2, 0: invalid syntax (syntax-error)
```

Why?

Comment: 99.9% chance: you forgot a closing parenthesis on the previous line.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're even trying it on Python 2, unless you imported the `print` function.

Comment: @Flippy - It technically could, but it always ends up being a parenthesis/bracket/brace.

Comment: Actually, if it were a missing quote, the interpreter would complain about an error while scanning a string literal. So no, it pretty much has to be a missing paren.

Comment: Also, whoever upvoted this, note that this question does not contain an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and is caused by a typo. Those are not indicators of a useful question.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 no, this is my actual code. I tested it.

Comment: Python runs this code successfully but Pylint is unhappy.

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when running this in python 2.7 (where print is a keyword, not a function)

Comment: Does your pylint have support for python 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this error when running pylint. But my pylint only had support for python2. So it errored:

```
$ pylint foo.py 
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module foo
E:  2, 0: invalid syntax (syntax-error)
```

So I did `pip3 install pylint`.

And then it all worked (or at least it got past the syntax error):

```
$ python3 -m pylint foo.py  | head
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module foo
C:  1, 0: Black listed name "foo" (blacklisted-name)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
.....
```

See here for more info on pylint for python2 and 3 in one system: https://askubuntu.com/questions/340940/installing-pylint-for-python3-on-ubuntu

Comment: Ok, I used `pylint ./pylint.py` instead of `python3 -m pylint foo.py`. I thought that pylint could read `#!/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Seemingly not - there's a shell script in the answer I linked that "sniffs the shebang" line to run the right pylint depending on the `#!` line. Don't know if the pylint project have a policy for not doing this...